# Hard drive won't connect to PC

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

I loaned my Seagate 500G GB external harddrive to a friend recently so that he could put some TV series on it, but he said (upon returning it) that after he started the transfer, for some reason it would no longer connect to his PC, along with several other devices.

At first I thought something had happened to his PC, so I didn't think much of it. However, after several attempts to connect it to my PC, it won't connect to mine either.

I have tried using different USB ports, and using different USB devices in the same port, I have connected my housemates External HDD (also Seagate) and it connects, I switched the cables, uninstalled and reinstalled my USB drivers, all to no avail. Does anyone know what might be happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the hard disk might be broken.

To rule out problems with USB drivers,
remove the drive from its casing and connect it to your motherboard directly,
using its supported adapter (SATA/IDE/...).

If that still doesn't work, then your hard disk is broken,
and you will have to look into recovery options.
I don't know any software in Windows, maybe somebody else can recommend.

If the disk works when connected to the motherboard directly but not via USB (through its case / enclosure), then you can try a different USB adaptor (SATA-to-USB, IDE-to-USB, depending on the disk's type) to see if the problem is in the adaptor of the case.

Comment: Actually I failed to mention that it attempted to connect the first time I reconnected it to my PC, but it failed to download the driver for it (unkown hardware I think was the error). Since then it wouldn't connect, and I think something might be loose in it because it rattles...

Comment: If it rattles, that's all the more reason to take it apart and reassemble. In some cases that alone can help.